# sorting associative array with numeric string values in php

Tags: php, array-multisort

```
$array = array(
     0 => array(
        'searchcountvalue' => 2,
        'pastsearchcountvalue' => 0,
        'abstract_count' => 694,
        'past_abstract_count' => 0 
    ),
    1 => array(
         'searchcountvalue' => "null",
        'pastsearchcountvalue' => 536,
        'abstract_count' => 0,
        'past_abstract_count' => 5667 
    ),
    2 => array(
         'searchcountvalue' => "null",
        'pastsearchcountvalue' => 12,
        'abstract_count' => 0,
        'past_abstract_count' => 123 
    ),
    3 => array(
         'searchcountvalue' => "null",
        'pastsearchcountvalue' => 324,
        'abstract_count' => 0,
        'past_abstract_count' => 456 
    ),
    4 => array(
         'searchcountvalue' => "null",
        'pastsearchcountvalue' => 56,
        'abstract_count' => 0,
        'past_abstract_count' => 345 
    ),
    5 => array(
         'searchcountvalue' => 212,
        'pastsearchcountvalue' => 'null',
        'abstract_count' => 6194,
        'past_abstract_count' => 0 
    ) 
);
```

I need this output, please help me

For Asc Order: based on `searchcountvalue`, `abstract_count`, `pastsearchcountvalue`, `past_abstract_count`

```
$array = array(
     0 => array(
         'searchcountvalue' => 2,
        'pastsearchcountvalue' => 0,
        'abstract_count' => 694,
        'past_abstract_count' => 0 
    ),
    1 => array(
         'searchcountvalue' => "null",
        'pastsearchcountvalue' => 536,
        'abstract_count' => 0,
        'past_abstract_count' => 5667 
    ),
    2 => array(
         'searchcountvalue' => "null",
        'pastsearchcountvalue' => 12,
        'abstract_count' => 0,
        'past_abstract_count' => 123 
    ),
    3 => array(
         'searchcountvalue' => "null",
        'pastsearchcountvalue' => 324,
        'abstract_count' => 0,
        'past_abstract_count' => 456 
    ),
    4 => array(
         'searchcountvalue' => "null",
        'pastsearchcountvalue' => 56,
        'abstract_count' => 0,
        'past_abstract_count' => 345 
    ),
    5 => array(
         'searchcountvalue' => 212,
        'pastsearchcountvalue' => 'null',
        'abstract_count' => 6194,
        'past_abstract_count' => 0 
    ) 
);
```

Comment: First, [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28875367/edit) your post so it's better readable for other users and you won't have much down votes that way.

Comment: If these data came from database, you should order it there not in php.

Comment: Thanks for ur idea .. but i need to display asc and desc with dynamic values . so i need to do it php.